# Having trouble to mock React component in Jest (RTL)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Basically, I am writing test for a local component called `LocalLink`, and I want to make sure it pass right prop  `slug` to the third package component  `ThirdPackageLink`, So I tried to mock the ThirdPackageLink , as following.  However, the following code does not work as expected, It seems like jest.mock does not work at all, it does not mock `ThirdPackageLink` at all.  I can only make it work if I put `jest.mock('@/path-to-component')` out side the describe block.

```
import LocalLink from './link';
import { within, render as renderInternal } from '@testing-library/react';

// If i put ``jest.mock('@/path-to-component')`` at here, it would work.

describe('LocalLink', () => {

  it('Should render correct slug', async () => {
  // For some reason, jest mock does not work here.
  jest.mock('@/path-to-component', () => ({
    ThirdPackageLink: ({ slug }: props) => `This component has slug: ${slug}`
  }));

    const { container } = render(<LocalLink path={path} />);
    expect(
      within(container).getByText(
        `This component has slug: ${path}`
      )
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

I tried the following way and does not work.

1. Use jest.doMock inside `it` block

```
 jest.mock('@/path-to-component', () => ({
    ThirdPackageLink: ({ slug }: props) => `This component has slug: ${slug}`
  }));
```

Comment: `I can only make it work if I put jest.mock('@/path-to-component') out side the describe block.` - you can make **what** work? If this works, what's the problem? Why do you need it inside the describe block? "works" and "does not work" are confusing terms, how does it work or not work, what are the expectations that are not being met, what are you trying to do?

Comment: So I am trying to write two tests, One is check with real Implementation  another is to check prop I passed to the mock component. In this case, the mock component would render as `This component has slug: ${slug}`. I can test if I child component have right prop. 

If I put jest.mock('@/path-to-component') out side the describe block, all the tests would  use the mock components.

Answer (score 0):

Given your further context, I'd probably do this.

Globally (in your test suite) wrap `ThirdPackageLink` in `jest.fn()` so you get the benefit of being able to mock it, but also use it's real implementation.

Here's what I mean:

```
jest.mock('@/path-to-component',() => {
  const { ThirdPackageLink } = jest.requireActual('@/path-to-component');
  return {
    ThirdPackageLink:jest.fn(ThirdPackageLink)
  }
});

import { ThirdPackageLink } from '@/path-to-component';

const mockedThirdPackageLink = jest.mocked(ThirdPackageLink); // if you're using typescript

describe('LocalLink',() => {
   it('should work with the real module',() => {
        // your test
   });

   it('should work with the mocked module',() => {
      mockedThirdPackageLink.mockImplementationOnce(({ slug }: props) => `This component has slug: ${slug}`)

    
      const { container } = render(<LocalLink path={path} />);
      expect(
        within(container).getByText(
          `This component has slug: ${path}`
        )
      ).toBeInTheDocument();      

   });

});
```

This way is my preference, but it's definitely not the only way.

The other is indeed to follow [the `jest.doMock` documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).

```
describe('LocalLink',() => {
   it('should work with the real module',() => {
        // your test
   });

   it('should work with the mocked module',() => {
       jest.doMock('@/path-to-component',() => ({ThirdPackageLink:jest.fn(({ slug }: props) => `This component has slug: ${slug}`)}))
    
       const { container } = render(<LocalLink path={path} />);
       expect(
         within(container).getByText(
           `This component has slug: ${path}`
         )
       ).toBeInTheDocument();      

   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Adam,
I actually tried the jest.doMock way, However, for some reason, The test still render with the default/actual implementation.

Comment: @SeanLiu I'm still confused by what you mean when you say "it works" when you put it outside the describe block - what is "it"? In any case, I hope I've shown you a way where you can get your whole test suite to run as desired with a global (outside the describe block mock).